# Remove Server header from response using URL rewrite not working for non ASP .net application.

Tags: angular, http, iis, http-headers, iis-8.5

Removing the server variable from response using url rewrite outbound rules is not working . application is angular 4 application and My server is windows 8 with iis 8.5 and I have my web.config data as shown below .

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
            <rule name="remove server header">
                <match serverVariable="Response_Server" pattern=".+" />
                  <action type="Rewrite" value="MyServer" replace="true" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need add this

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
     <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true"/>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This was added for IIS 10.0. Original question was for IIS 8.5.